# How to install selenium webdriver with java support on CentOS 6.3?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, centos6

How to install Selenium WebDriver with Java support on CentOS 6.3 ?

I have Java running on my machine. Any help in the above direction is solicited. Everywhere I am getting help on installing WebDriver on CentOS with Python support.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is self-explanatory.  First, install Java on the system, then install Python, then create a Python webdriver script, like so.  Nothing else to it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("selenium")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "Google" in driver.title
driver.close()
```